# Admob Ads Not Showing in React Native Signed Apk

Tags: admob, react-native, signed-apk

I am using `react-native-admob` to display admob ads in my react native app. Everything was working fine. Ads were loading in debug app as well as in release apk. 
Now, I want to publish app in playstore and for that I need signed apk. I used steps described in react-native docs to generate signed apk.
Now, I have separate apk files for each architecture and a universal apk for all architectures but ads are not showing in signed apk. I don't know the reason.
Kindly help please.

Comment: hi please help me. i integrated the react native google mobile ads successfully in debug mode but when i am generating APK file ads not showing. does i need to do any other configuration for showing in apk file.

Comment: please check the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As android operating system is also from google and they don't allow users to install apps that are not scanned by their antivirus.
When you have an unsigned apk you can install it by enabling settings "install apps from unknown resources" but when you have signed apk it has to be scanned by google in order to display ads. 
According to google

> Google scans millions of apps every day to ensure they’re safe for users. If you have been asked to submit your APK, or if you have a problem serving Google ads in your Android application, please complete the form below.

So you have to either submit signed apk if you want to display ads on this [link](https://support.google.com/admob/contact/android_APK_submission?hl=en)

or you can check the box appears when you install a signed app saying "Send This App to google for Scanning"
Google will start serving ads in your signed apk.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wait a couple days and they'll start showing up. I'm guessing your api key is fresh and Google loves taking their time to start sending you actual ads in the beginning. I've heard the typical wait is 3 days, but mine took 6-7.

Comment: My admob account is 1 week old.. and I had waited for 2 days when I created the account before they start serving ads.

Comment: The account age doesn't really matter. Once you start requesting real ads with your key, that's when the waiting time starts and it's going to take a couple days from there.

Comment: it's been 15+ Days since my ads are not being served.
but AdMob dashboard shows the rise of ad requests.